# All devices targets on xcode become "unavailble"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have tried to install xcode 4.6 together with my existing xcode 6.3.
I have face issues during installation.
one of the solutions was to run this command:

```
/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

after that i could not run under devices , for all devices that i have it gives me this error : 
[image]

did any one face this before ?

**UPDATE :**

itunes also can not see my devices.
I have reinstalled xcode but no changes.

Comment: Try quitting Xcode while you phone is still connected, and then reopen Xcode.

Comment: What you can also try is change the Command Line Tools in the Prefrences -> Locations

Comment: i have tried that also

Comment: Have u tried uninstalling both xcodes and reinstalling just xcode 6.3 again? It asks u to install additional components. May be it can fix this issue.

Comment: yes i have tried, but did not change things.

Comment: What about mac osx update? Tried?

Comment: it can be a solution, but as i have the latest one i did not know how to reinstall the OSX.
it could be by doing recovery but i have a doubt to loose my data..can you explain how it should be done please ?

Comment: Have you actually tried to do what the error message suggests? :D rebooting and reconnecting the device?

Comment: Uninstalled your old xcode and installed latest xcode. Also update the iTune, then try to reconnect your device.

Comment: these two softwares are up to date. for xcode i did this but no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the Mac OS resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you will be able to find out some helpful points from these links.

[Xcode iOS project only shows "My Mac 64-bit" but not simulator or device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377970/xcode-ios-project-only-shows-my-mac-64-bit-but-not-simulator-or-device)

[Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x)

[Xcode doesn't see my iOS device but iTunes does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087985/xcode-doesnt-see-my-ios-device-but-itunes-does)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html

still if it is not done please apologize me.