# Sending my Flutter App to my real iPhone instead of the simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

I've paid the $99/year just now for the Individual Developer License.  My phone is plugged in, but "flutter devices" still isn't recognizing it.  How do I send my app to my phone?

Comment: You have to fix some things in XCode. Did you try these?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087985/xcode-doesnt-see-my-ios-device-but-itunes-does
https://flutter.io/setup-macos/#deploy-to-ios-devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the default Xcode workspace in your project by running `open ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in a terminal window from your Flutter project directory.
2. In Xcode, select the *Runner* project in the left navigation panel.
3. In the Runner target settings page, make sure your Development Team is selected under *General* → *Signing* → *Team*. When you select a team, Xcode creates and downloads a *development certificate*, registers your device with your account, and creates and downloads a provisioning profile.

**You should do step 1-3 only once**. From now on, your Mac gets certificates and provision profiles, and you can run "flutter devices" to see registered device.

Comment: Still not seeing it in flutter devices... xcode did recognize my phone though.

Comment: Yeah, Xcode pushed it to my phone!  Still can't be in debug mode with flutter tools, but at least I can deploy a production app to my phone for testing!

Comment: You can try below steps:
From Xcode -> select Window -> Organizer. Now under Devices, select your device. If it is not ready for development then click use for development.

Comment: Yeah, that all works... I can push code to my phone.  But "flutter devices" and VSCode do not see it as a target.

Comment: Hi Randal, how about result of running: "flutter doctor"

Comment: It says I need to install brew for some of the tools... that's probably the ones I'm missing to have the tools recognize my iphone.  However, I *cannot* install brew, because I'm heavily invested in macports, and they don't play well together (I tried at one point and ended up with a mess).  At least I can test the code on the phone... just can't debug it.

Comment: I solved the error :  " ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -8".   thanks!!