# Mac recognizes iPhone, Xcode does not

Tags: ios, xcode

The following images ilustrates my problem and I have seen dozens of topics about the same subject and none of the solutions work for me, like for example: [Xcode doesn't see my iOS device but iTunes does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087985/xcode-doesnt-see-my-ios-device-but-itunes-does)

[image]

[image: ode,]

I'm using a Virtual Machine with MacOS Mojave and Xcode 10.2.1. Any ideas?