# Xcode 13.2.1 won't recognize iOS devices on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, apple-m1

I have an App on the app store that works fine. Last January ('21) I bought a Macbook Pro M1 (now running Monterey 12.1) and have shifted all my Xcode files to it. Everything builds fine when I have "Any iOS Device (arm64)" selected, or any of the device simulators, but not when I have my MacBook Pro selected as the device to run the app on, nor in either of the two iPhones I can connect via USB. I've been trying for 2 days to get either one of my iPhones (8 plus and 6s, both running iOS 15.2.1) to be recognized by Xcode (13.2.1) and show up in the Device list without any luck. They show up in Apple ID, in Apple Music when plugged in via USB, and pretty much everywhere else, just not in Xcode.

I've tried everything on this SO thread to no avail: [Xcode doesn't see my iOS device but iTunes does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087985/xcode-doesnt-see-my-ios-device-but-itunes-does/27398715)

I've tried "automatically manage signing", and done it manually. I've unplugged, updated, and restarted in multiple different configurations. I've tried all different types of provisioning profiles. All software versions match each other on all devices and are up to date.

Anyone else experiencing this? I'm totally stumped.

Comment: I solved the first part, getting the app to run on my Mac with automatic signing. I had been running Xcode using Rosetta. I just had to close Xcode, go to applications folder, then control click and select get info and then uncheck "Open using Rosetta". Then reopen Xcode, build & run, and it works!