# Is there a way to reset the cache of apps compiled for iPad on an M1 machine using "My Mac (Designed for iPad)"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-m1, simulator

I am running my app with device: "My Mac (Designed for iPad)".

[image]

I am trying to debug a problem where the iPad does not seem to detect when I grant permission to receive push notifications. This issue is only reproduceable on a physical iPad, not on a simulator.

I was able to reproduce the issue by running the app with the option "My Mac (Designed for iPad)". However, I cannot find the way to reset the cache of the app and completely delete it from my M1. Whenever I re-run (after cleaning Xcode and derived data directory), I do not get prompted for the notifications again and it seems to be getting the answers I replied the first time, i.e. it has push notifications accepted and the user is still signed in.

Is there a way to somehow reset the cache, delete the app from the M1 (or something else) and run the app fresh whenever I want?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just for your information, I do not have an actual iPad. I am testing with the new feature shown in the attached picture which makes the M1 simulate a physical iPad (which can use the camera and microphone), and get push notifications.

Edit 2: Adding more info.
XCode 13.3
MacOS 12.2

Comment: If I understood correctly, Xcode doesn't recognize your iPad device.

If I'm right, please check these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087985/xcode-doesnt-see-my-ios-device-but-itunes-does

Comment: Hello @Emm. Actually, I do not have an iPad to test. People who tested it told me that. The only way I can reproduce this on my machine is running it with that option given by the M1, which simulates being a hardware iPad and allows me to use the M1's camera and microphone as if it were an iPad (different from the iPad simulator which is all software based).

Answer (score 1):

To clear the cache, delete this folder:

`~/Library/Containers/{CFBundleName}`

To delete the app, right-click on the app icon when the app is launched, select Options->Show in Finder. Delete the highlighted `.app` file.